# Softening vs Smoothing Length... Is There a Difference?

Tags: simulation, smoothing

I have a simple questions on terminology.  Is there a difference between softening length and smoothing length?  I have been using the 2 terms interchangeably as the minimum distance between particles for calculating particle interactions, and have not found any direct comparison of the 2 terms.
For context, I use computational/numerical physics simulations (specifically the GIZMO code) to simulate gaseous disks around galactic centers, where "particles" represent some mass of hydrogen. Perhaps it's also important to state that I am specifically looking at gravitational interactions at this point. I just want to make sure I am not missing something important.

Thank you

Comment: What area is this terminology of? You are assuming that we're all experts in the precise area you are looking at :-)

Comment: Apologies.  I use simulations (specifically the GIZMO code) to simulate gaseous disks around galactic centers, where the particles represent some mass of hydrogen.  So the area is in terms of computational/numerical physics, applying to the interactions between hydrogen particles.  Perhaps it's also important to state that I am specifically looking at gravitational interactions at this point. Hope this clarifies things @WolfgangBangerth :)

Comment: @dcro Please, edit your question accordingly instead of using comments.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, I've edited the question appropriately; I hope that format/presentation of the question is adequate.  Thanks